# rotate object to touched coordinates

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm doing a simple game in SpriteKit, and have little problem. I would like my character/player(SKSpriteNode) to rotate himself to position where I touched the screen, so he always face touched to coordinates. I know there something like zRoatation, but I don't know how to calculate an angle. I will be really grateful for any tips.

Comment: Have you looked at atan2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer thanks to Antoine Lecaille.

float newAngle = -atan2(newPosition.x - currentPosition.x, newPosition.y -currentPosition.y) + [self degToRad:180];